# Assign a stored procedure result as a bool variable on C#

Tags: c#, stored-procedures

Hello Is it possible to store the result of a stored procedure as a true/false value in a bool variable? Something like:

1)

```
bool var = ExecuteScalar("sp_name", parameters);
```

or

2)

```
bool var = ClassName.getValue(parameters);
```

where
getValue() is a method that has this code:

```
return dataBase.ExecuteDataSet("sp_name", parameters);
```

I want to know if a customer has a card or not. I was thinking of using what I have right now which is basically the second option above, and then create a condition whether the row count is more than zero. But I also want to know if there are any other methods I can use.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do:

```
DataSet ds = dataBase.ExecuteDataSet("sp_name", parameters);
return ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count>0; //true if record found; false if no rows
```

Assuming your proc is simply doing a select using the parameters in the where clause. Something like:

```
select col1 from table a where condition=@parameter
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't say which DBMS you are using. SQL Server, for example, does not have a `bool` data type, but you can make your sproc return an `int`, which you can test for nonzero, e.g.

```
bool result = ((int) ExecuteScalar("sp_name", parameters)) != 0;
```

NOTE: I have not tested this, but you could try making the sproc return a `bit` instead. This is still an integer value as far as SQL Server is concerned, but ADO.NET should detect it and automatically cast it to `bool` for you. It certainly does for sproc parameters.

Answer (score 0):

[ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx) returns an Object. So no, #1 above would throw an error. Assuming your stored procedure returns a value that can be converted to true/false, you'd have to do something like this:

```
bool var;
bool.TryParse(ExecuteScalar("sp_name", paramaters).ToString(), out var);
```

Comment: `TryParse` expects a string I think, not an object

Comment: Yes, it does, I edited my answer shortly after I answered it when I realized I forgot the .ToString() call (refresh your page).